# Css display none not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1215px) {
 #menu {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

This is not working, the div is still visible. However, if I change the div to `<div class="menu">` instead of `<div id="menu">` and the css :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1215px) {
   .menu {
       display:none;
   }
}
```

it works. Why is this happening?

***EDIT***

This is what Inspector says:

```
element {
    display: block;
}
#listMenuTop {
    display: none;
}
#listMenuTop {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

But both display:none are crossed. Where does the display: block; comes from ?

***EDIT 2***

I found the problem. A js function was overwriting the css display property:

```
document.getElementById('listMenuTop').style.display='block';
```

What I want to do is to hide #listMenuTop when screen >= 900px and when screen < 900px to be able to display/hide #listMenuTop from a button. The problem is that when #listMenuTop is displayed on a screen < 900px it doesn't hide if i resize screen to more than 900px, because that js function is always overwriting the display property.

Comment: Is it possible you have another `#menu` somewhere? There should only ever be 1 ID of something on a page.

Comment: Should work [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QENQd/)

Comment: @BeatAlex no. i don't have another #menu.

Comment: Probably the element when it has the id it's overwitten by another selector. Maybe there is a selector with bigger specificity or another selector is defined after the one you mentioned. Check it with developer tools.

Comment: It should work. Check the css of the element within dom inspector. What does it shows?

Comment: `element{display:block;}` come from some javascript code. Please check whole page and script execution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1215px) { 
    #menu {   
        display:none !important;
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your **inspector says you have inline styles** added by Javascript (question updated) as:

```
<div id="listMenuTop" style="display: block;"> ... </div>
```

than your CSS should look like this:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1215px) {
      /* Following will override inline style */
      #listMenuTop[style] {
           display: none !important;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I would not suggest someone to use `!important` when it is possible to fix it with just the selector. *A more specfic selector has more priority*

Comment: That is why the `important` is not my primary answer. But still, if it was addressed as `!important` first place, than you need to override it same way, means with `!important`.

Comment: Still if he uses `!important` it is better to remove the `!important` selector. However i see you updated your code, edit your code once so i can take back my -1. But still suggest to never use `!important`.

Comment: It is just practice... I would never suggest using `!important`, but sometimes you have no control over existing CSS, you can just add new (which happens often).